# Вывести состав заказа в label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Изучаю swift. Заранее прошу прощения за кривой код и глупый вопрос.
Задание такое, есть пивбар, в нем три позиции пива, изменяю их количество кнопками + -. По нажатию на кнопку Sell в label должна отобразиться информацию о выбранном пиве, если выбрано две позиции, то вывести две, если три, то три и т.д. Запарился на моменте как вывести все возможные комбинации? Неужели нужно перечислять все возможные комбинации? А если пива 50 позиций, невозможно же перечислить все комбинации. Ниже прикладываю код.
помогите, пожалуйста, дойти мыслью...

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  egor
//
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var countOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countThree: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameCrinica: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameHeineken: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameCorona: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelInfo: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stateButtonSell: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stateButtonEndDay: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateButtonStartDay: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPlusCorona: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMinusCorona: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPlusHeineken: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMinusHeineken: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPlusCrinica: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMinusCrinica: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stateButtonSell.isEnabled = false
        labelMinusHeineken.isEnabled = false
        labelMinusCrinica.isEnabled = false
        labelMinusCorona.isEnabled = false
        
        nameCorona.text = "Corona Beer"
        countOne.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCorona)"
        countTwo.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterHeineken)"
        countThree.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCrinica)"
        }
    
    @IBAction func buttonMinusCorona(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Manager.shared.counterCorona -= 1
        countOne.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCorona)"
        if Manager.shared.counterCorona == 0 {
            labelMinusCorona.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            labelPlusCorona.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPlusCorona(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Manager.shared.counterCorona += 1
        countOne.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCorona)"
        if Manager.shared.counterCorona == Manager.shared.beerCorona.quantityBottle {
            labelPlusCorona.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            labelMinusCorona.isEnabled = true
        }
        if Manager.shared.counterCorona > 0 {
            stateButtonSell.isEnabled = true
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonMinusHeineken(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Manager.shared.counterHeineken -= 1
        countTwo.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterHeineken)"
        if Manager.shared.counterHeineken == 0 {
            labelMinusHeineken.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            labelPlusHeineken.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPlusHeineken(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Manager.shared.counterHeineken += 1
        countTwo.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterHeineken)"
        if Manager.shared.counterHeineken == Manager.shared.beerHeineken.quantityBottle {
            labelPlusHeineken.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            labelMinusHeineken.isEnabled = true
        }
        if Manager.shared.counterHeineken > 0 {
            stateButtonSell.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonMinusCrinica(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Manager.shared.counterCrinica -= 1
        countThree.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCrinica)"
        if Manager.shared.counterCrinica == 0 {
            labelMinusCrinica.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            labelPlusCrinica.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPlusCrinica(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Manager.shared.counterCrinica += 1
        countThree.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCrinica)"
        if Manager.shared.counterCrinica == Manager.shared.beerCrinica.quantityBottle {
            labelPlusCrinica.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            labelMinusCrinica.isEnabled = true
        }
        if Manager.shared.counterCrinica > 0 {
            stateButtonSell.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonSell(_ sender: UIButton) {
//        labelInfo.text = "Ваш заказ: \n \(Manager.shared.beerCorona.nameBeer) - (\(Manager.shared.counterCorona)) л. \n \(Manager.shared.beerHeineken.nameBeer) - (\(Manager.shared.counterHeineken)) л. \n \(Manager.shared.beerCrinica.nameBeer) - (\(Manager.shared.counterCrinica)) л."
        Manager.shared.beerCorona.quantityBottle -= Manager.shared.counterCorona
        print(Manager.shared.beerCorona.quantityBottle)
        Manager.shared.counterCorona = 0
        countOne.text = "\(Manager.shared.counterCorona)"
        if Manager.shared.counterCorona == 0 {
            labelMinusCorona.isEnabled = false
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonStartDay(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonEndDay(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

Manager:

```
import Foundation

class Manager {
    
    static let shared = Manager()
    private init(){}
    
    
    var beerCorona = Beer(nameBeer: "Corona", quantityBottle: 10, price: 6)
    var beerHeineken = Beer(nameBeer: "Heineken", quantityBottle: 10, price: 4)
    var beerCrinica = Beer(nameBeer: "Крыница", quantityBottle: 10, price: 2)
    
    var counterCorona = 0
    var counterHeineken = 0
    var counterCrinica = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример для playground, если я правильно вас понял

```
let beer1 = 4
let beer2 = 0
let beer3 = 1

var label = "Ваш заказ: \n"

if beer1 > 0 {
    label += "Пиво 1 - \(beer1) л. \n"
}
if beer2 > 0 {
    label += "Пиво 2 - \(beer2) л. \n"
}
if beer3 > 0 {
    label += "Пиво 3 - \(beer3) л. \n"
}

print(label)
```